# ScheduledExecutorService executing run parallelly with other codes just below it

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService for the first time, and not able to understand it's behaviour. I have written a simple code and assuming it to execute in sequence but it does not.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    AtomicInteger runTimeCounter = new AtomicInteger(1);
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    int totalCountToRun = 4;
    int threadSleepTime = 5;
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (runTimeCounter.get() <= totalCountToRun) {

                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
                    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    String time = formatter.format(date);
                    //create threaddump files in temp location
                    System.out.println("from task "+time);
                    //Increment the counter
                    runTimeCounter.getAndIncrement();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            } else {

                executorService.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }, 5, threadSleepTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++ ){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String time = formatter.format(date);
        //create threaddump files in temp location
        System.out.println("from for "+time);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }

}
```

It prints :

```
from for 22:17:27 IST
from task 22:17:27 IST
from task 22:17:32 IST
from for 22:17:32 IST
from task 22:17:37 IST
from for 22:17:37 IST

from task 22:17:42 IST
from for 22:17:42 IST
```

Can someone please guide me what exactly happening here and how can I run the code sequentially.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? You have the main thread and you have the single thread in the scheduler. Both running in parallel. What is the issue you have?

Comment: Now I Understand it, thanks!